# Why does this request work in Insomnia/Postman but not Python Requests?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, postman, insomnia

Here is the cURL command, works fine and returns data:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.reserveamerica.com/jaxrs-json/products/AK/1180246?prdId=2400&detailed=true&gal=14&fc=true&gad=2023-06-27&next=false&displayGISMap=true' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
  --header 'Authorization: eyJraWQiOiJiOUZPc0pUblF1NTRBdVEzWlR1NE55Ylkzakp3cVg5WFJZZ3NvQlBDOThBPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.b1d--A6EMth6jz5f0yMJjRW6IlIzZSUdUWT-AIk1ElduvuTi7AxGQu7pJbxC8MMZrX75k0xg8tXcKhyc85BwrME1lBoZ-hCejPGKbqgku3aiHLyMU0X5A0-IaLLblW1FnvQktEQT_ukbs-vASUSnNIALCZZUG25SIpeWxe3XcZrX7n1I60jIGN8ZSAre4l-5lOz5fmFyuT7Ac4fREByBNczng6Whr5Z6PqeMzRbqXuFAeNhHEuwfBWSwcOEZF63F0pkwnf2NzhXkukMq5pbMfDJ57uqoWGehTVpkLqoCitOLDM97B5UtWttBCxEIuvU_hH6Hcqm-stEYnondSJO5jQ' \
  --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0' \
  --header 'a1Data: {"sessionID":"4D441B5AE76AE0D435FBE1F3A32380FE.ue1-prod-aspiraone-web-10","sessionType":"SELFSERVICE","maxInactive":1800000,"AWSALB":"3MbtREdsquTV2MIZtkGpTIuB8kVWmwiOf+Q9GK0mWy6OsjQ8VBr6sSGzhiE2Xa/iPoTilVAH0sML5EK6NMLgipGThJ+z6rQKpGj5e2HI2Y2/6xjyrHr+ViXh58I4","AWSALBCORS":"3MbtREdsquTV2MIZtkGpTIuB8kVWmwiOf+Q9GK0mWy6OsjQ8VBr6sSGzhiE2Xa/iPoTilVAH0sML5EK6NMLgipGThJ+z6rQKpGj5e2HI2Y2/6xjyrHr+ViXh58I4"}'
```

And the corresponding requests version, returns 400 and no data:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.reserveamerica.com/jaxrs-json/products/AK/1180246"

querystring = {
    "prdId": "2400",
    "detailed": "true",
    "gal": "14",
    "fc": "true",
    "gad": "2023-06-27",
    "next": "false",
    "displayGISMap": "true",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "a1Data": '{"sessionID":"4D441B5AE76AE0D435FBE1F3A32380FE.ue1-prod-aspiraone-web-10","sessionType":"SELFSERVICE","maxInactive":1800000,"AWSALB":"3MbtREdsquTV2MIZtkGpTIuB8kVWmwiOf+Q9GK0mWy6OsjQ8VBr6sSGzhiE2Xa/iPoTilVAH0sML5EK6NMLgipGThJ+z6rQKpGj5e2HI2Y2/6xjyrHr+ViXh58I4","AWSALBCORS":"3MbtREdsquTV2MIZtkGpTIuB8kVWmwiOf+Q9GK0mWy6OsjQ8VBr6sSGzhiE2Xa/iPoTilVAH0sML5EK6NMLgipGThJ+z6rQKpGj5e2HI2Y2/6xjyrHr+ViXh58I4"}',
    "Authorization": "eyJraWQiOiJiOUZPc0pUblF1NTRBdVEzWlR1NE55Ylkzakp3cVg5WFJZZ3NvQlBDOThBPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.b1d--A6EMth6jz5f0yMJjRW6IlIzZSUdUWT-AIk1ElduvuTi7AxGQu7pJbxC8MMZrX75k0xg8tXcKhyc85BwrME1lBoZ-hCejPGKbqgku3aiHLyMU0X5A0-IaLLblW1FnvQktEQT_ukbs-vASUSnNIALCZZUG25SIpeWxe3XcZrX7n1I60jIGN8ZSAre4l-5lOz5fmFyuT7Ac4fREByBNczng6Whr5Z6PqeMzRbqXuFAeNhHEuwfBWSwcOEZF63F0pkwnf2NzhXkukMq5pbMfDJ57uqoWGehTVpkLqoCitOLDM97B5UtWttBCxEIuvU_hH6Hcqm-stEYnondSJO5jQ",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some potential issues with your API:

- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) config;
- Gateway config;

Perhaps the request is constructing an invalid query. I suggest replacing the parameters with an implicit query string in the URL.

I encountered errors like that due to the request library incorrectly parsing the data type.